# jQuery - each of one list before each of another list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a task so I need understand:
If I have one list with hex color's and I need add before title as name of this color:

```
<ul attr="pa_varnish_color">
  <li>25acfa</li>
  <li>ffffff</li>
  <li>000000</li>
  <li>ffff05</li>
</ul>
```

then I have:

```
<div class="plans-description">Blue</div>
<div class="plans-description">White</div>
<div class="plans-description">Black</div>
<div class="plans-description">Other</div>
```

Count of li of course equal to count of `<div class="plans-description">`.
So I need each div to be prepend each li. Like this:

```
<ul attr="pa_varnish_color">
  <li>
    <div class="plans-description">Blue</div>
    25acfa
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="plans-description">White</div>
    ffffff
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="plans-description">Black</div>
    000000
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="plans-description">Other</div>
    ffff05
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: We here don't write code for you, we just punch you in the side of solution that seems right.

Comment: I have tried many things and lost a lot time. I know only that I need to use each function. But the problem for is to understand how to prepend each element of one list to each element of another list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var i=1;
$(".plans-description").each(function() {
  $("ul li:nth-child("+ i +")").prepend( $(this).clone(true));
  i++;
});
```

---

@Olli K:
Actually $.each provides the index for you, so you can just write:

```
$(".plans-description").each(function(i) {
  $("ul li:nth-child(" + (i + 1) + ")").prepend($(this).clone(true));
});
```

---

http://jsfiddle.net/washington_guedes/br1034r6/8/

---

Comment: Works for me. So if I understand I need to create counter, then with nth-child i get elements one by one in loop and prepend clone of each div. Right... Sounds good:))

Comment: Actually `$.each` provides the index for you, so you can just write: `$(".plans-description").each(function(i) { $("ul li:nth-child(" + (i + 1) + ")").prepend($(this).clone(true));
    });`

Answer (score -1):

```
var ARRAY_OF_COLORS = {"25acfa": "blue", .... };

$( "li" ).each(function( index ) {
      $(this).append("<div class='plans-description'>" + ARRAY_OF_COLORS[$(this).html()]+ "</div>");
    });
```

Comment: This is part of the solution, but your code appends the same `<div>` to each `<li>`, and it'll go *after* the `<li>` content, not before, as requested in the question.

Comment: @Egor - the `prepend` is not the *only* problem... Read Pointy's entire comment

Comment: I have tried like this too. Because I didn't know right solution.